# ContentManager in console mode?

Tags: c#, xna

Is there a way to setup a ContentManager without using a GraphicsDevice?  It's a console app..

The problem is I get a "Reach profile" not supported, is there a way to make it without needing DirectX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ContentManager takes an IServiceProvider. It is best to create a class that implements IServiceProvider with your own behavior rather than just using Game or GraphicsDevice.

From msdn:

"Caution
When creating a new ContentManager, if no instance of Game is otherwise required by the application, it is often better to create a new class that implements the IServiceProvider interface rather than creating an instance of Game just to create a new instance of GraphicsDeviceManager."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb195757.aspx